# Consulta en Django

Tags: python, django

tengo los siguientes modelos en mi proyecto mi objetivo era obtener los cocteles que tuviesen todos los ingredientes en almacen pero me devuelve todos los cocteles que al menos tengan un ingrediente en almacen. Como se realiza esa consulta
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida saludoss

menu/models.py

```
class Cocteles(models.Model):
 
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo_ingredientes=models.ManyToManyField(Tipo_Ingrediente,through='CoctelIngrediente')
    precio = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    precio_descuento = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    categoria = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_LABEL, max_length=2,blank=True, null=True)
    imagen=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    descripcion=models.TextField(default='hola')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='cuba')
    hidden=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    precio_dinamico=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class CoctelIngrediente(models.Model):

    cocteles=models.ForeignKey(Cocteles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo_ingredientes=models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Ingrediente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
```

almacen/models.py

```
class Tipo_Ingrediente(models.Model):

    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    precio=models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    cantidad=models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    id_activo=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    precio_dinámico=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
class Almacen(models.Model):

    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    costo=models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    tipo=models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Ingrediente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad=models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    creado=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hidden=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

en la view.py

```
def make_menu(request):
    
    cocteles=Cocteles.objects.filter(tipo_ingredientes__cantidad__gt=0)
    context={
        'cocteles':cocteles
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/carta.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para obtener solamente los cocteles que tienen todos sus ingredientes en el almacén, tienes que realizar una consulta con un filtro adicional en la relación ManyToMany.

Primero se obtienen todos los ingredientes que están en el almacén y luego se filtran los cocteles que tienen exactamente la misma cantidad de ingredientes que los ingredientes en el almacén.

Seria de esta forma:

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef

# tus modelos...

def make_menu(request):
    # obtenemos todos los ingredientes disponibles en almacén
    ingredientes_almacen = Tipo_Ingrediente.objects.filter(almacen__cantidad__gt=0).values_list('id', flat=True)
    # obtenemos todos los cocteles que tienen todos sus ingredientes en el almacén
    cocteles = Cocteles.objects.filter(tipo_ingredientes__in=ingredientes_almacen).annotate(
        ingredientes_count=Count('tipo_ingredientes')
    ).filter(
        ingredientes_count=Cocteles.tipo_ingredientes.through.objects.filter(cocteles=OuterRef('pk')).count()
    )
    context={
        'cocteles':cocteles
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/carta.html',context)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su rapida respuesta pero cuando la ejecuto me sale el siguiente error 'This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.' me podrias explicar un poco mas el ultimo filter que realizas

Answer (score 0):

La repuesta de Codimbo es la aceptada solo que tuve que cambiar el OuterRef por Subquery y pasarle los id que tiene ingredientes_almacen

```
def make_menu(request):
    # obtenemos todos los ingredientes disponibles en almacén
    ingredientes_almacen = Tipo_Ingrediente.objects.filter(almacen__cantidad__gt=0,almacen__hidden=False).values_list('id', flat=True)
    # obtenemos todos los cocteles que tienen todos sus ingredientes en el almacén
    cocteles = Cocteles.objects.filter(tipo_ingredientes__in=ingredientes_almacen).annotate(
        ingredientes_count=Count('tipo_ingredientes')
    ).filter(
        ingredientes_count=Cocteles.tipo_ingredientes.through.objects.filter(cocteles=Subquery(ingredientes_almacen)).count()
    )
    context={
        'cocteles':cocteles
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/carta.html',context)
```